# Non-blocking script with timers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, timeout, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm doing a test to perform a non-bloking script in order to render a **large jQuery-UI accordion**, so instead of using a loop, which will always block the browser until done, I'm trying with **timers** to render each part separately, but it seems to create an infinite loop (not sure why since it should reach the exit condition):

```
(function(){
    var accordion = $('.accordion').accordion({collapsible: true});
    var source = $('.source');
    var sourceCopy, timerCount = 0, times = 100;
    var createNewTab = function(i) {
        sourceCopy = source.children().clone();
        sourceCopy.filter('h3').text('Title ' + i).end().appendTo(accordion);
        accordion.accordion('refresh');
    };

    (function run(){
        var timer;
        createNewTab(timerCount);
        timerCount++;
        /*while (timerCount < times) {  // commented out to avoid endless loop
            timer = setTimeout(run, 0);
        }*/

        // OLD BROWSER-BLOCKING VERSION WITH LOOP. IT WORKS BUT BLOCKS BROWSER UNTIL DONE
        /*for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            createNewTab(i);
        }*/

    })();
})();
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="source">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rutrum malesuada molestie. Duis sem massa, mollis eget lacinia sit amet, blandit a tortor. Etiam ultrices facilisis tempor. Ut sagittis, nisi nec vestibulum condimentum, dolor urna gravida dui, nec posuere nibh nibh a dui. Nunc eleifend convallis varius. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut quam sed augue commodo fermentum quis nec turpis. In interdum aliquet mi, a placerat orci sagittis sed. Sed fermentum urna eu arcu consequat, vel egestas enim eleifend. Proin augue tellus, hendrerit nec quam vitae, placerat malesuada ligula. Integer faucibus ullamcorper odio sagittis dapibus. Nam sed ex vel metus bibendum aliquam vel sit amet ante. Maecenas ultrices sem sagittis est finibus, id fermentum dolor molestie.    
        <p>Donec ipsum ipsum, pharetra eu arcu eu, lobortis convallis augue. Morbi sit amet tortor dui. Nam eget lacinia turpis. Quisque efficitur vulputate sapien, non dignissim dolor malesuada ut. Integer non diam et magna maximus tincidunt quis viverra tortor. Ut ut mauris ut tortor faucibus pellentesque. Nunc iaculis, elit luctus malesuada lobortis, tellus elit egestas orci, at cursus tellus nisl molestie neque. Pellentesque convallis nisi ut purus dignissim, a vestibulum libero condimentum. Sed congue leo eget condimentum vulputate. Nunc accumsan massa id tempor luctus. Vivamus orci lectus, ornare vestibulum arcu eget, egestas luctus ipsum. Maecenas sodales, mi eu volutpat tempor, justo mi laoreet lacus, vel viverra lacus augue ut felis. Aenean ullamcorper risus eget ante venenatis viverra. Morbi malesuada erat ante, quis egestas lacus tristique sed.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion"></div>
```

The source code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luismartin/drwpqydw/)

How could I work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `while` with `if`. Your `setTimeout` already does the looping by calling the function over and over until `timerCount == times`.

```js
(function(){
    var accordion = $('.accordion').accordion({collapsible: true});
    var source = $('.source');
    var sourceCopy, timerCount = 0, times = 100;
    var createNewTab = function(i) {
        sourceCopy = source.children().clone();
        sourceCopy.filter('h3').text('Title ' + i).end().appendTo(accordion);
        accordion.accordion('refresh');
    };
    
    (function run(){
        var timer;
        createNewTab(timerCount);
     timerCount++;
        if (timerCount < times) {
            timer = setTimeout(run, 0);
        }
    })();
})();
```

```css
.source {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="source">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rutrum malesuada molestie. Duis sem massa, mollis eget lacinia sit amet, blandit a tortor. Etiam ultrices facilisis tempor. Ut sagittis, nisi nec vestibulum condimentum, dolor urna gravida dui, nec posuere nibh nibh a dui. Nunc eleifend convallis varius. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut quam sed augue commodo fermentum quis nec turpis. In interdum aliquet mi, a placerat orci sagittis sed. Sed fermentum urna eu arcu consequat, vel egestas enim eleifend. Proin augue tellus, hendrerit nec quam vitae, placerat malesuada ligula. Integer faucibus ullamcorper odio sagittis dapibus. Nam sed ex vel metus bibendum aliquam vel sit amet ante. Maecenas ultrices sem sagittis est finibus, id fermentum dolor molestie.

        <p>Donec ipsum ipsum, pharetra eu arcu eu, lobortis convallis augue. Morbi sit amet tortor dui. Nam eget lacinia turpis. Quisque efficitur vulputate sapien, non dignissim dolor malesuada ut. Integer non diam et magna maximus tincidunt quis viverra tortor. Ut ut mauris ut tortor faucibus pellentesque. Nunc iaculis, elit luctus malesuada lobortis, tellus elit egestas orci, at cursus tellus nisl molestie neque. Pellentesque convallis nisi ut purus dignissim, a vestibulum libero condimentum. Sed congue leo eget condimentum vulputate. Nunc accumsan massa id tempor luctus. Vivamus orci lectus, ornare vestibulum arcu eget, egestas luctus ipsum. Maecenas sodales, mi eu volutpat tempor, justo mi laoreet lacus, vel viverra lacus augue ut felis. Aenean ullamcorper risus eget ante venenatis viverra. Morbi malesuada erat ante, quis egestas lacus tristique sed.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    
</div>
```

[Fixed JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bs840kr/)

Comment: Oh my!! I can't believe I couldn't see that! Thanks a lot!